# Selenium 3.0 ExpectedConditions issue

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automated-tests

Using a `click()` implementation as follows, selenium will act as if it clicked the button, and will expect the next screen. But the webpage will not receive the click so the next screen will not pop up. I don't really understand what it is going on, maybe some of you encountered this issue before. Here's the click implementation:

```
public static void click(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, DEFAULT_WAIT_FOR_ELEMENT)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by))
        .click();
}
```

**Note:** With a thread.sleep of 2 seconds, the button is indeed clicked. But as we all know, no one wants thread.sleep.

**Note2:** This issue will not happen as often on selenium 2.53

**Note3:** I'm currently using FireFox 49.0.1, with geckodriver 0.11.1

Answer (score 4):

I will give you some examples of how I have my wait implemented, perhaps it'll help you be more flexible.

I create a basic waitUntil method with a time parameter with a default time.

```
    private void waitUntil(ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition, Integer timeout) {
    timeout = timeout != null ? timeout : 5;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.until(condition);
}
```

Then I can use that helper method to create my wait for displayed or wait for clickable.

```
    public Boolean waitForIsDisplayed(By locator, Integer... timeout) {
    try {
        waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator),
                (timeout.length > 0 ? timeout[0] : null));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can do the similar with elementToBeClickable.

```
    public Boolean waitForIsClickable(By locator, Integer... timeout) {
    try {
        waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator),
                (timeout.length > 0 ? timeout[0] : null));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So we can make a click method to do our clicks to use this:

```
    public void click(By locator) {
    waitForIsClickable(locator);
    driver.findElement(locator).click();               
}
```

The reason I make the waitForIsDisplayed and waitForIsClickable is because I can reuse those in my assertions to make them less brittle.

```
assertTrue("Expected something to be found, but that something did not appear",
            waitForIsDisplayed(locator));
```

Also, you can use the wait methods with the default time specified in the method (5 seconds), or can do:

```
waitForIsDisplayed(locator, 20);
```

That would wait a max of 20 seconds before throwing the exception.

Comment: The problem is that the button is displayed,  and clickable, so no exception thrown. As I see this issue,  either the button has no functionality when Selenium clicks it,  or Selenium 's click is dull. I am trying to understand this. Got back on Selenium 2.x and it is working just fine.

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd attempt to debug. Also, check locator you're using, perhaps use the parent or child of the one you have been attempting to click. I'm not aware of any changes to click method for selenium 3

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason is it didn't find element while it trying to check element clickable. As per implementation of `elementToBeClickable` **it assumes element present**.

I would suggest to use [QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) for selenium webdriver. It provides extended webdriver and [webelement](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/javadoc/index.html) so when you are using this framework you don't need to use such waits. In case you really required wait it provides element level methods for wait, for instance,

```
ele.waitForVisible()
```

Comment: It found the element,  it clicked the element and went ahead to the next action. The web page didn't received the click. Or the click Selenium executed was blank,  with no effect.

Comment: in this case you should try with 'nativeEvents' capability. See [DesiredCapabilities][https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities] for reference