# AndroidElement and WebDriver wait method issue

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I want to be able to use multiple time same Method in my mobile automation suite. Means that each time i just calling Method and updating only "elementName" ( AndroidElement).

I tried:

```
 public void waitForScreenToLoad(AndroidElement elementName){
        (new WebDriverWait(driver,30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(elementName.getId())));
    }
```

In my test i will call it this way

```
MessageCenterScreen message = new MessageCenterScreen(driver);

base.waitForScreenToLoad(message.addCardButton);
```

But my test is failing because it cannot find an element which exists.

I use Page Factory model to locate an elements

```
   @FindBy(id = "widget_loading_fab_button")
        public AndroidElement addCardButton;
```

This way it works perfectly, but the problem is :  **I Dont want to duplicate my method all the times.**

```
public void waitForCardManagementScreenToLoad() {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("widget_loading_fab_button")));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public void waitForScreenToLoad(AndroidElement element){
        (new WebDriverWait(driver,30)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    }
```

Use **ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf**

Answer (score 0):

I'll paste what I had helped someone in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110192/selenium-3-0-expectedconditions-issue/40116392#40116392)

I create a basic waitUntil method with a time parameter with a default time.

```
    private void waitUntil(ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition, Integer timeout) {
    timeout = timeout != null ? timeout : 5;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.until(condition);
}
```

Then I can use that helper method to create my wait for displayed or wait for clickable.

```
    public Boolean waitForIsDisplayed(By locator, Integer... timeout) {
    try {
        waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator),
                (timeout.length > 0 ? timeout[0] : null));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can do the similar with elementToBeClickable.

```
    public Boolean waitForIsClickable(By locator, Integer... timeout) {
    try {
        waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator),
                (timeout.length > 0 ? timeout[0] : null));
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So we can make a click method to do our clicks to use this:

```
    public void click(By locator) {
    waitForIsClickable(locator);
    driver.findElement(locator).click();               
}
```

The reason I make the waitForIsDisplayed and waitForIsClickable is because I can reuse those in my assertions to make them less brittle.

```
assertTrue("Expected something to be found, but that something did not appear",
            waitForIsDisplayed(locator));
```

Also, you can use the wait methods with the default time specified in the method (5 seconds), or can do:

```
waitForIsDisplayed(locator, 20);
```

That would wait a max of 20 seconds before throwing the exception.